# How to compile Boost 1.39 in VS2010?

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2010, vc10

I am trying to upgrade our C++ project from VS2005 to VS2010 and so far all seems good except I need to recompile our Boost libraries (v1.39) in VS2010 (i.e. with vc100 - the versions we have are vc80).  I do not (at this stage) want to upgrade Boost as I'd prefer to complete the VS2005 to VS2010 upgrade first without doing a Boost upgrade at the same time.

The problem I have is that Boost 1.39 comes with bjam and the version we have does not support/know about msvc10.0.  I tried this:

C:\libs\boost_1_39_0>**bjam toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage**

But, I get this:

C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2/tools\msvc.jam:733: in configure-really
*** argument error
* rule path.make ( native )
* called with: (  )
* missing argument native
C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2/util\path.jam:44:see definition of rule 'make' being called
C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2/tools\msvc.jam:184: in configure
C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2/tools\msvc.jam:137: in msvc.init
C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2/build\toolset.jam:38: in toolset.using
C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:465: in process-explicit-toolset-requests
C:/libs/boost_1_39_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:545: in load
C:\libs\boost_1_39_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import
C:\libs\boost_1_39_0\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:138: in boost-build
C:\libs\boost_1_39_0\boost-build.jam:16: in module scope
C:\libs\boost_1_39_0>

When I look at msvc.jam, it does not seem to support msvc-10.0 (no surprise as I doubt vc10.0 was out when Boost was at 1.39).

So did a bit of research and found that maybe I need to b2 instead of bjam, but I have very little experience of compiling Boost (just used precompiled libs before), so I would like to ask is it possible to get b2 that will work with Boost 1.39?  Or is it possible to make bjam work with vc10.0?

Essentially, I just need to compile Boost 1.39 with vc-10.0 (VS2010) as simply as possible please!  I will be very grateful to anyone who can tell me how to do this!

Thank you in advance........ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a more recent version of bjam to build boost 1.39.

- download and unzip the [current boost version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/)
- in a VS10 command prompt `cd` to the root of the freshly unzipped boost folder
- execute `bootstrap.bat`.  This should build `bjam.exe` in that folder
- `cd` to the root folder of boost 1.39 and copy `bjam.exe` over
- execute your bjam command: `bjam toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage`

Comment: Fraser - you're a star! Thank you so much, this is excatly what I needed. Boost 1.39 successfully compiled with vc10.0 :)  Many thanks!

Comment: @namford Great :)  Although I'd recommend upgrading boost to the current version as soon as you can too.  There are tons of improvements (new libraries, optimisations and bugfixes) between 1.39 and 1.49

Comment: Actually, because there have been changes in the regex libs, we are having to upgrade anyways! D'oh... :)  It was worth attempting to do it without though, so thanks again and at least I learned a whole host of stuff!